# How to reduce live log data?

Tags: bash

A program produces a log file, which I am watching. Unfortunately, the log file includes sometimes 50 times the same Line 1. 
Is there a possibility to get instead of

program.sh

```
Line 1
Line 1
Line 1
Line 1
...
Line 1
Line 1
Line 2
```

just something like:

program.sh

```
Line 1
 \= repeated 43 times
Line 2
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, that the date/time is at each line at the beginning. That would start to count each second.

Comment: So update the question. What's the expected output in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk 'function prnt() { print p; if (c>1) print "  \\= repeated " c " times"; }
    p && p != $0{prnt(); c=0} {p=$0; c++}; END{prnt()}' file
Line 1
  \= repeated 43 times
Line 2
```

Comment: Can we improve it a little bit, by NOT printing "\= repeated 1 times"  If it is 1?